# Using a trained classifer on a new DataFrame

Tags: python, machine-learning

I have built a classifier, trained and tested on labeled data. Now I want to test it further by making predictions on a dataset **without** the labels. I already know the labels myself, but I want to remove them for the purpose of testing, and have it print out the values with a 0 prediction so I can compare the accuracy myself. I'm using the following code to iterate through my dataset and make a prediction for each row in the DataFrame;

```
malware = set()

for index, row in dataset.iterrows():
    res = clf.predict([row])
    if res == 0:
        malware.add(index)

print(malware)
f.write(str(malware) + "\n")
```

It seems to be working, however it's not a quick process, is there a better way or anything I can do to speed it up?

Comment: Are you using scikit-learn? If so,you can pass in the whole dataframe and the result will be an array of labels.

Comment: @Ding. I am yeah, but when I try using .predict on the whole dataset I then can't seem to print out the index values, all I get is an array of the prediction values.

Comment: Assuming you want to get all the index with predicted label 0, use `dataset.index[clf.predict(dataset) == 0]`

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks very much @Ding. I've turned the above into a workable solution :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of work I have turned the comment from Ding into a workable answer that is much quicker. My new code is;

```
from collections import OrderedDict

malware = []

malware.append(OrderedDict.fromkeys(dataset.index[clf.predict(dataset) == 0]))

print (malware)
```

Thanks very much Ding!

Answer (score 0):

Using a for loop to iterate through elements in a dataset is slow in general. What you want to do is apply your function to every element in the column(s), and generate a series of labels according to the result. (Assuming you're using Pandas for the dataframe, by the way)

```
 labels=dataset.apply(clf.predict)
```

You can then just scan through this series with a for loop. That should be relatively instant.